# BitAuth Live Server Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I have a local server, which is connected to my online database. I have been using bitAuth as my authentication method, and it was working all great, until I moved all my files onto my server.

BitAuth comes with a default administrator account, admin(pw admin). I tried using this to sign in, but it returns an "invalid username/password".

I saw someone else has mentioned a similar issue [here](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/210884/), but there isn't any solution.

Comment: make sure tht user belongs to some groups .. recently i got a hard time on this ..

Comment: yes the user does belong to the group "admin" :/

Comment: remove the user authentication ..and then edit user password .. also make sure that the pswd is correct as doc says ..

Comment: it's not the solution. I have solved this issue completely, and added as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself:

I first traced the password verification process used by BitAuth.

Which will bring you to this piece of code:

```
function CheckPassword($password, $stored_hash)
{
    $hash = $this->crypt_private($password, $stored_hash);
    if ($hash[0] == '*')
        $hash = crypt($password, $stored_hash);

    return $hash == $stored_hash;
}
```

If you were to print the $hash and the $stored_hash, you would realise that the 2 hashes are different.(as expected, since if it was the same then the login would have passed)

At this point, the only possible reason would be that the crypt_private() function has produced a hash that is different to the stored hash. I then looked into the crypt_private() function:

```
function crypt_private($password, $setting)
{
    $output = '*0';
    if (substr($setting, 0, 2) == $output)
        $output = '*1';

    $id = substr($setting, 0, 3);
    # We use "$P$", phpBB3 uses "$H$" for the same thing
    if ($id != '$P$' && $id != '$H$')
        return $output;

    $count_log2 = strpos($this->itoa64, $setting[3]);
    if ($count_log2 < 7 || $count_log2 > 30)
        return $output;

    $count = 1 << $count_log2;

    $salt = substr($setting, 4, 8);
    if (strlen($salt) != 8)
        return $output;

    # We're kind of forced to use MD5 here since it's the only
    # cryptographic primitive available in all versions of PHP
    # currently in use.  To implement our own low-level crypto
    # in PHP would result in much worse performance and
    # consequently in lower iteration counts and hashes that are
    # quicker to crack (by non-PHP code).
    if (PHP_VERSION >= '5') {
        $hash = md5($salt . $password, TRUE);
        do {
            $hash = md5($hash . $password, TRUE);
        } while (--$count);
    } else {
        $hash = pack('H*', md5($salt . $password));
        do {
            $hash = pack('H*', md5($hash . $password));
        } while (--$count);
    }

    $output = substr($setting, 0, 12);
    $output .= $this->encode64($hash, 16);

    return $output;
}
```

Nothing seems to be out of place. It then occured to me that PHP could have produced different hashes in different versions. I then contacted my server support, and found out that the server was using PHP5.2, whilst my server was using PHP5.4.

The [solution](http://kb.site5.com/php/how-to-enable-php-5-3-on-your-site5-account/) was simple, I added the following line into my .htaccess file in CodeIgniter,

> AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php

Which in my server, would enable PHP5.3 instead of PHP5.2. This has made the crypt_private() function produce the same hash from the provided password string with the stored hash.

Another solution to this issue is that one could essentially just create a new account, go into your database and "activate" the account. Since this new hash is generated by whatever version of PHP your server is using, it solves the problem.

I hope the 2 solutions I provided would help other BitAuth users out there who are facing the same problem.

BitAuth is a great authentication library, if only they would put this into their documentation to make users aware of this potential error.

Good day.